# query on two conditions without in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like the following

```
select * from conv_master cm  
where cm.`from_currency_id` in (select currency_id from currency_master where currency_code = 'USD')
and cm.to_currency_id in (select currency_id from currency_master where currency_code = 'EUR');
```

Is there a way to rewrite this query without using in. 
Thanks

Comment: To make the answer marked *as correct* really correct, you must add that the  `currency_id` is PK of `currency_master`. See alternative answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
select * from conv_master cm 
inner join currency_master m1  on cm.from_currency_id = m1.currency_id
inner join currency_master m2  on cm.to_currency_id = m2.currency_id
where m1.currency_code='USD' and m2.currency_code='EUR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the IN predicate with INNER JOIN, but only in case that the column selected in the subquery is primary or unique key. Otherwise you get duplicated results from the join.

So more general answer (not assuming that `currency_id` is PK of `currency_master`) would be in adding a distinct subquery to remove possible duplicates:

```
select CM.* from conv_master cm 
inner join (select distinct currency_id from currency_master where  currency_code='USD') m1  
on cm.from_currency_id = m1.currency_id
inner join (select distinct  currency_id from currency_master where currency_code='EUR') m2  
on cm.to_currency_id = m2.currency_id
```